# Queue Sidekiq job on Rails app start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I need to add a job to the Sidekiq queue when my Rails app starts, to update some data, but I don't know where is the best place to do it.

Right now, I've wrote this on my `application.rb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    config.after_initialize do
        MyWorker.perform_async
    end
end
```

But the problem is that when I run the `sidekiq` command it will also load the Rails stack, so I'll end up with 2 jobs on the queue.

Is there any other way of doing that? This is my first big Rails app and my first time with Sidekiq, so I don't know if I'm not understanding things correctly. That might not be the right way of doing that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A better solution would be to create an initializer `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
        # You code goes here
    end
end
```

Comment: Using `config.on(:startup)` (answer below) seems much better than patching `.configure_client`, it's a first class Sidekiq concept. Also, `.configure_client` is called when you start the Rails server process, while `configure_server` is only called when the Sidekiq process starts

Answer (score 8):

We were having issues w/ Redis connections and multiple jobs being launched.

I ended up using this and it seems to be working well:

```
if defined?(Sidekiq)
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.on(:startup) do
      already_scheduled = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.any? {|job| job.klass == "MyWorker" }
      MyWorker.perform_async unless already_scheduled
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably [foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) suits for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but none of this worked for me - would still start the job several times. I came up with the following solution:

I have a Class to do the actual Job:

```
class InitScheduling
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform
    # your code here
  end
end
```

And I have an inizializer, which would normally start 3 Times, every time, something loads the Rails environment. So I use the Job as a state variable that this job is already scheduled:

```
# code in inizilizer/your_inizilizer.rb

 Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
   all_jobs = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
   # If this is True InitScheduling is already scheduled - don't start it again
   unless all_jobs.map(&:klass).include?("InitScheduling")
     puts "########### InitScheduling ##############"
     # give rails time to build before running this job & keeps this initialization from re-running
     InitScheduling.perform_in(5.minutes)
     # your code here
   end
  end
```